# How can I override an entity form with the same date?

Tags: datetime, entities

I have an entity form that requires choosing from a date field.
I wanted to override a submitted entity form if there is an existing submitted form with the same date.
I was looking for a solution in the net, but I was not able to find anything useful.
Thank you in advance for those who can help!

Answer (score 0):

When new entity created you need to implement check (if entity with certain date exists) in your FORM_ID_submit() function. If so, use entity_load() to edit existing entity, if not, create new one. Also I recommend using [EntityFieldQuery](https://www.drupal.org/node/1343708) and [Entity Metadata Wrappers](http://www.pixelite.co.nz/article/how-use-entity-metadata-wrappers-drupal-7) to deal with entities.